# Change Text inside div after specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I'm having a jQuery Countdown (http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/) for a football match. When the countdown complete, it display oncomplete function.

I want the jQuery to change the 'Live' word inside the div to Full Time after 90 minutes from the Countdown Complete.

Here is the Code

```
<div id="countdown">
    <div class="dash days_dash">
        <span class="dash_title">days</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash hours_dash">
        <span class="dash_title">hours</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash minutes_dash">
        <span class="dash_title">minutes</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash seconds_dash">
        <span class="dash_title">seconds</span>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
        <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="message" id="complete" style="display: none;">Live</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#countdown').countDown({
            targetDate: {
                'day':      11,
                'month':    4,
                'year':     2016,
                'hour':     13,
                'min':      0,
                'sec':      0
            },
            onComplete: function() { 
            $('#countdown').addClass('ended');
            $('#complete').slideDown(); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not to use pure JavaScript?

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you mean you want to replace the text "Live" with "Full Time"?

Comment: I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add 90 minutes to a date object using the following: `var newDate = new Date(originalDate.getTime() + 90 * 60000);`

Using this new date, you can then check if the current date matches or exceeds the newdate. Getting the current date is done through `Date.now()`. Adding this all up leads to the following:

```
// Original date = March 30 2016 14:00:00
var minutes = 90,
    originalDate = new Date(1459339200000);
    timedDate = new Date(originalDate.getTime() + minutes * 60000);

// timedDate = originalDate + 90 minutes.

if (Date.now() >= timedDate) {
    // We are now 90 minutes later
    // Replace div text.
}
```

Inside the `if-statement` you can replace the div text. I would advise to use only one div and just replace the text; as opposed to having two seperate divs.

Comment: He wants to set a timer ;)

Answer (score 0):

To build upon what @Matthjs said in the comments. This code would work well:

```js
    var specificDate = 1459346400000; //which is what March 30th 2016 is
    var timeleft = specificDate - Date.now();
    setInterval(update, timeleft);
    function update(){
    if (Date.now() >= specificDate) { 
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Time's Up";
     }   
     }
```

```html
<div id="output">Still got time!</div>
```

This will check the if loop right when the time up.

Comment: (a) It doesn't address the 90 minute addition and (b) By using setInterval it will repeat every `timeleft` instead of firing just once.

Comment: Yeah i didnt change the comment @Timeout after i made an edit